# How to see my next data and previous data without database and listbox?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have 3 button. There are prev, next and add. i have a text file with 6 lines.
So as the form load, it's only display 3 lines ascending text, the other 3 lines is appear when i click next button. But i don't know how to make it appear.
This is my next button code

```
private void next_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  string[] baca;
  baca = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@path.Text);    
  nama.Text = baca[3];
  npm.Text = baca[4];
  alamat.Text = baca[5];
}
```

I want it to display another next lines with only 1 next button.

Comment: Is this winforms?  WPF?  Webforms?

Comment: Read the data *once* and use a form level var to index what to show.

Comment: it's windows forms

Comment: can you edit the code? @Plutonix

Comment: How would *you* learn?  `@path.Text` seems wrong

Comment: that's exactly how i browse my text file

Comment: You say "So as the form load, it's only display 3 lines ascending text" is this true? Then you already know how to display lines. Just do thesame in the buttonClick function

Comment: yes, but then how to show another line if i have 9 lines with only 1 button

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the current line in a variable so that when you click in buttons you can use this variable as reference.

Another thing, instead of setting the fixed indexes set a var as code below. 
Ps: If you are using web plataform storage the current item in a hidden field.

```
    private int i = 0; // or in hidden field

    private void next_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string[] baca;
        baca = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@path.Text);

        nama.Text = baca[i];
        npm.Text = baca[i+1];
        alamat.Text = baca[i+2];

    }
```

Comment: But if you don't increment the index then next clicks will do the same thing again and again

Answer (score 0):

The answer has already been stated by @Plutonix, and I quote "Read the data once and use a form level var to index what to show."

```
int firstIndex = 0;
var baca = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@path.Text).ToList();
private void next_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    firstIndex++;  
    nama.Text = baca[firstIndex];
    npm.Text = baca[firstIndex + 1];
    alamat.Text = baca[firstIndex + 2];
}
```

However, if you don't want a form level variable for some reason this would work:

```
private void next_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var baca = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@path.Text).ToList();
    int firstIndex = 1 + baca.FindIndex(nama.Text);    
    nama.Text = baca[firstIndex];
    npm.Text = baca[firstIndex + 1];
    alamat.Text = baca[firstIndex + 2];
}
```

Remember, this is not the best way, and will not work if there are duplicates.